# Can't set MySQL query cache

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set `query_cache_size` on MySQL.

There is no option for it in the workbench options page so I opened up the mysql utility console and set:

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 16m
```

This hasn't set the cache size though.  In the examples they were at prompt `mysqld` and I am at prompt `mysqluc`.  When I type `mysqld` it says "The utility mysqld is not accessible (from the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities)."

I have tried navigating there with cmd prompt and running command on the exe but I get same issue.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the mysql server

if you are on linux, do this

```
 service httpd restart
```

on windows, go to run and write  -> services

You will see a huge list, search mysql . Right click mysql service -> stop and then start it.